# How to train xgboost with TF-IDF

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to train the model to classify short texts. I do the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1000)
train['vector']=vectorizer.fit_transform(train['item_name'])
train=train.drop('item_name',axis=1)
y=train.category_id
train=train.drop('category_id',axis=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train,y, test_size=0.10,stratify=y,random_state=42)
import xgboost as xgb
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I get an error:

> ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or categorical.  When
> categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter
> `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.vector

Answer (score 0):

> When categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter enable_categorical must be set to True.vector

You should be training `XGBClassifier` with `TfidfVectorizer` transformation results only. Right now you're passing the original un-vectorized text sentences also, which causes the above `ValueError` to be raised.

The simplest solution is to set up a two-step pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ("vectorizer", TfidfVectorizer()),
  ("classifier", XGBClassifier())
])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, be aware that XGBoost estimators are interpreting sparse data matrices differently from the regular Scikit-Learn estimators. To get the correct/meaningful results, you should additionally convert the sparse data matrix to a dense data matrix.

See [Training Scikit-Learn based TF(-IDF) plus XGBoost pipelines](https://openscoring.io/blog/2021/02/27/sklearn_tf_tfidf_xgboost_pipeline/)

Comment: To avoid posting a big chunk of code, I deleted a few lines (replaced by ...). I delete item_name column, split dataset into x and y etc...
The error message shows that the problem is with vector column